# Running multiple instances of the same program slows down all of them

Tags: java, performance

I have a single-threaded program that utilizes nearly 100% CPU when run alone.  If I instantiate multiple instances of it on separate prompts, they all slow down considerably (about 8 fold). I am running jre version 1.7.0_25 on Ubuntu 12.04 with a Intel® Core™ i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz × 12 and 64 GB RAM.  What could be causing the slow down?  Surely, the programs can not be competing for the same CPU.  And, I have always made sure that I run lesser instances than there are cores.  I appreciate any insight.
Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: What do the programs do? Any external resource they are dependent on? (e.g. database, network, filesystem)

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the program does. But the CPU isn't the only resource a program needs. The memory, the hard-disk, the network: if several programs access them concurrently, they will slow down.

Comment: Could you shortly describe what the programm uses and what it doing? From this point there is whole bunch of possible answers, but with this lack of info, any of them will be just guessing.

Comment: regarding "same CPU": you have just 6 real cores but each has more or less a cpu internal thread scheduler so it appears as if there were twice as much. 1 thread @ 100% per real core is therefore probably rather close in overall performance of 2 threads @ 100% per real core. (compare i5 vs i7 benchmarks, they don't double in overall performance)

Comment: OK, more details.  The program picks random square regions (Monte Carlo) from an image that is loaded into memory once when the program starts and calculates certain features on the image using fiji libraries.  Each instance takes the sides of the region as (wxh) an argument and calcualtes the features over each randomly chosen region, for a specified amount of times before writing the results onto a .csv file.  So, it does depend on network/disk, once at startup (the image is read over a network), and once at the end, while writing out the results.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance creates a separate JVM with a distinct initial heap (defined by -Xms JVM argument) and program resources. If you have too many instances, there is no surprise the OS will be swapping memory to disk and CPU's context will switch continuously between the java processes.

Comment: I am asking for a maximum heap size of 10g and the minimum heap size is the default: uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 1046179712.  I typically have over 70% of the 64G RAM available on my machine before I start these programs.  So, I am quite confident it can't be swapping.